# Calling another Volley request after first one is finished

Tags: android, json

For example, in my first request I'm getting the movie's ID and in the second volley request, I'll be searching info about the movie by using the movie's ID I got in my firs request. Is there a better method to do this?

Comment: Yes, there is a better way to do this.I suppose you press a button or a widget to get the movie's ID (perhaps the movie's title or icon).Create a simple widget or overwrite whatever you are using as a button ,and add to it a new variable movieID ,don't forget getter and setter and whenever you create the movie Icon/title or whatever it is ,you also add .setmovieID to whatever your ID is.Let me know if this helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a queue for request inside the volley library. You can add multiple requests into the queue. But in my opinion you should get all the data at the same time. It is not worth it for sending multiple requests for a movie(If you are not requests a lot of data).But if you wanna request multiple times you can callback from onResponse interface.

```
<!-- Inside the class variable -->
RequestQueue queue;
<!-- Inside the onCreate or whatever you want -->
queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

<!--1st request for movie -->
try {
        jsonObject.put("movieId",movieID);
        jsonObject.put("somedata",somedata);
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,YOUR_IP_ADDRESS,jsonObject,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // Call second request here and add it to queue again
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }) {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("id","1");
                params.put("name", "myname");
                return params;
            };
        };
        queue.add(jsObjRequest);

    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```